# How to get width and height from a body in box2d?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am working on a game in `Libgdx` engine. I have to get width and height from a body in `box2d`. is their any way to get width an d height from a body in `box2d`??

Comment: You can have a look at one of my old Gists: https://gist.github.com/nooone/8363982. It can create a bounding box for a Body, but it is not completely implemented. Look at the `PhysicsUtil`.

Comment: @noone ya its very nice. It seems the right way I am looking. Is it possible to re size the bodies? I have already seen to destroy fixture and recreate it but height is not proper of actor and body...

Comment: No, resizing is not possible.

Comment: @noone   please can you consider this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729244/body-height-width-is-different-from-sprite-height-width-in-box2d-libgdx

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I am not really sure, but this seems to be quite complicated, since a box2d body can consist of several Fixtures, where each one has a different shape.

Are you just looking for the width and height of the bounding-box?

Then you might have to iterate through the fixture list of the body and evaluate the shapes in there, look at the position of the shapes and calculate the bounding box. Unfortunately, this doesn't look like a comfortable way.

Comment: ohk actualy I have only one fixture int it and that is PolygonShape and I have set it as setAsBox. So any idea???

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem before and this is the solution worked with me, you have to loop over all fixtures then start to get the b2AABB rectangle of each fixture and combine them all together, then get the width and height of the combined AABB

```
    b2AABB aabb;
    b2Transform t;
    t.SetIdentity();
    b2Fixture* fixture = nearBody->GetFixtureList();
    while (fixture != NULL) {
        const b2Shape *shape = fixture->GetShape();
        const int childCount = shape->GetChildCount();
        for (int child = 0; child < childCount; ++child) {
            b2AABB shapeAABB;
            shape->ComputeAABB(&shapeAABB, t, child);
            shapeAABB.lowerBound = shapeAABB.lowerBound;
            shapeAABB.upperBound = shapeAABB.upperBound;
            aabb.Combine(shapeAABB);
        }
        fixture = fixture->GetNext();
    }

    CCPoint lowerVertex = aabb.lowerBound;
    CCPoint heigherVertex = aabb.upperBound;
    bodyWidth = heigherVertex.x - lowerVertex.x;
    bodyHeight = heigherVertex.y - lowerVertex.y;
```

Comment: b2AABB aabb must be initialized with something like aabb.lowerBound = b2Vec2(FLT_MAX,FLT_MAX); aabb.upperBound = b2Vec2(-FLT_MAX,-FLT_MAX); Otherwise aabb.Combine(shapeAABB) may use random initial values.

Answer (score 1):

check b2World.cpp, there are some code might help you:

```
void b2World::DrawDebugData() {
    ...
    for (b2Body* b = m_bodyList; b; b = b->GetNext()) {
        const b2Transform& xf = b->GetTransform();
        for (b2Fixture* f = b->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext()) {
            ...
            DrawShape(f, xf, b2Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.3f));
        }
    }
    ...
}

void b2World::DrawShape(b2Fixture* fixture, const b2Transform& xf, const b2Color& color) {
    ...
    case b2Shape::e_polygon: {
            b2PolygonShape* poly = (b2PolygonShape*)fixture->GetShape();
            int32 vertexCount = poly->m_count;
            b2Vec2 vertices[b2_maxPolygonVertices];
            for (int32 i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
                //they are polygen's vertices, you can use these to get the height / width
                vertices[i] = b2Mul(xf, poly->m_vertices[i]);
            }
            m_debugDraw->DrawSolidPolygon(vertices, vertexCount, color);
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with when following [this](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-flgt-home/) libgdx tutorial.

```
float w2 = 0f
float h2 = 0f
b.body.fixtureList.each { Fixture fixture ->
    if(fixture) {
        if(fixture.shape.type == Shape.Type.Circle) {
            w2 += fixture.shape.radius * 2
            h2 += fixture.shape.radius * 2
        } else if(fixture.shape.type == Shape.Type.Polygon) {
            PolygonShape shape = fixture.shape as PolygonShape
            Vector2 vector = new Vector2()

            def vectors = []
            shape.vertexCount.times {
                shape.getVertex(it, vector)
                vectors.add(new Vector2(vector.x, vector.y))
            }

            vectors.sort {it.x}
            w2 = (vectors.first().x).abs() + (vectors.last().x).abs()

            vectors.sort {it.y}
            h2 = (vectors.first().y).abs() + (vectors.last().y).abs()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also posted this answer on an identical thread on gamedev.stackexchange.com
I know that this is a very old thread but I just made my own way of getting the size of a Body here: https://github.com/Wasupmacuz/Box2DBodySize
Here's the code if links are too spooky for you:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ChainShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.EdgeShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape;

/**
 * Finds the size (width and height) of a body by checking its fixtures' shapes
 */
public class Sizerinator3000
{
    public static Vector2 getBodySize(Body body)
    {
        float maxTop = 0, maxRight = 0, maxBottom = 0, maxLeft = 0;
        for(Fixture f : body.getFixtureList())
        {
            MyVector4 vec = outerVals(f);
            if(vec.a > maxTop)
                maxTop = vec.a;
            if(vec.b > maxRight)
                maxRight = vec.b;
            if(vec.c > maxBottom)
                maxBottom = vec.c;
            if(vec.d > maxLeft)
                maxLeft = vec.d;
        }
        
        return new Vector2(Math.abs(maxRight - maxLeft), Math.abs(maxTop - maxBottom));
    }
    
    public static Vector2 getBodySize(Body body, float scale)
    {
        float maxTop = 0, maxRight = 0, maxBottom = 0, maxLeft = 0;
        for(Fixture f : body.getFixtureList())
        {
            MyVector4 vec = outerVals(f).scale(scale);
            if(vec.a > maxTop)
                maxTop = vec.a;
            if(vec.b > maxRight)
                maxRight = vec.b;
            if(vec.c > maxBottom)
                maxBottom = vec.c;
            if(vec.d > maxLeft)
                maxLeft = vec.d;
        }
        
        return new Vector2(Math.abs(maxRight - maxLeft), Math.abs(maxTop - maxBottom));
    }

    /**
     * Changing which method is called based on the fixture's shape
     * @param fixture the current fixture being analyzed
     * @return the outermost points of the fixture's shape
     */
    private static MyVector4 outerVals(Fixture fixture)
    {
        Shape shape = fixture.getShape();
        Shape.Type type = shape.getType();
        MyVector4 size = new MyVector4();
        switch(type)
        {
        case Polygon: 
        size = shapeVals((PolygonShape)shape);
        break;
        case Chain: 
        size = shapeVals((ChainShape)shape);
        break;
        case Edge: 
        size = shapeVals((EdgeShape)shape);
        break;
        case Circle: 
        size = shapeVals((CircleShape)shape);
        break;
        }
        
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the outermost points for a PolygonShape
     * @param s the shape
     * @return the maximum upper, lower, left, and right values; given by the vertices
     */
    private static MyVector4 shapeVals(PolygonShape s)
    {
        MyVector4 size = new MyVector4(); // top, right, bottom, left
        for(int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++)
        {
            Vector2 probe = new Vector2();
            s.getVertex(i, probe);
            if(probe.x > size.b) // right
                size.b = probe.x;
            if(probe.x < size.d) // left
                size.d = probe.x;
            
            if(probe.y > size.a) // top
                size.a = probe.y;
            if(probe.y < size.c) // bottom
                size.c = probe.y;
        }
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the outermost points for a ChainShape
     * @param s the shape
     * @return the maximum upper, lower, left, and right values; given by the vertices
     */
    private static MyVector4 shapeVals(ChainShape s)
    {
        MyVector4 size = new MyVector4(); // top, right, bottom, left
        for(int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++)
        {
            Vector2 probe = new Vector2();
            s.getVertex(i, probe);
            if(probe.x > size.b) // right
                size.b = probe.x;
            if(probe.x < size.d) // left
                size.d = probe.x;
            
            if(probe.y > size.a) // top
                size.a = probe.y;
            if(probe.y < size.c) // bottom
                size.c = probe.y;
        }
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the outermost points for an EdgeShape
     * @param s the shape
     * @return the maximum upper, lower, left, and right values; given by the vertices
     */
    private static MyVector4 shapeVals(EdgeShape s)
    {
        MyVector4 size = new MyVector4(); // top, right, bottom, left
        Vector2 probe = new Vector2();
        s.getVertex1(probe);
        if(probe.x > size.b) // right
            size.b = probe.x;
        if(probe.x < size.d) // left
            size.d = probe.x;
        
        if(probe.y > size.a) // top
            size.a = probe.y;
        if(probe.y < size.c) // bottom
            size.c = probe.y;

        s.getVertex2(probe);
        if(probe.x > size.b) // right
            size.b = probe.x;
        if(probe.x < size.d) // left
            size.d = probe.x;
        
        if(probe.y > size.a) // top
            size.a = probe.y;
        if(probe.y < size.c) // bottom
            size.c = probe.y;
        
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the outermost points for a CircleShape
     * @param s the shape
     * @return the maximum upper, lower, left, and right values; given by radius and position
     */
    private static MyVector4 shapeVals(CircleShape s)
    {
        MyVector4 size = new MyVector4(); // top, right, bottom, left
        size.a = s.getPosition().y + s.getRadius(); // top
        size.b = s.getPosition().x + s.getRadius(); // right
        size.c = s.getPosition().y - s.getRadius(); // bottom
        size.d = s.getPosition().x - s.getRadius(); // left
        
        return size;
    }
    
    /**
     * using this just to store the variables easily
     */
    private static class MyVector4
    {
        public float a, b, c, d;
        
        public MyVector4()
        {
            this.a = 0;
            this.b = 0;
            this.c = 0;
            this.d = 0;
        }
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public MyVector4(float a, float b, float c, float d)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void set(float a, float b, float c, float d)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }
        
        public MyVector4 scale(float val)
        {
            this.a *= val;
            this.b *= val;
            this.c *= val;
            this.d *= val;
            
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((Sprite)body.getUserData()).getWidth();
```

---

```
((Sprite)body.getUserData()).getHeight();
```

use it.. it should answer your query if i guessed it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a wrapper class if you're just using polygonShape as a box. And store the relevant information like width, height and position in the wrapper class variables.

Answer (score 0):

(If you are changing body size (adding/removing fixtures) in runtime you might need some modification when changing body size to the following method but it should work.)

Note: I am using Java+jbox2d

The easiest I can think of is storing the height and width in the object yourself like when creating the body

```
float objectHeight;
float objectWidth;
```

When you are creating the body (specifically shape).
Just add all dimentions togather

```
objectWidth = fixture1Shape.width + ...;
objectHeight = fixture1Shape.height + ...;
```

then it's just making custom methods in object like

```
float getWidth(){
   return objectWidth;
}

float getHeight(){
   return objectHeight;
}
```

now you can get the exact width and height of the body of the object.
using

```
o1.getHeight();
o1.getWidth();
```

[considering o1 is where you have located the object say `Object o1 = fixture.getUserData();` or `Object o1=body.getUserData()`]

You might need to create a new object of desired class and cast that to object before calling the methods

```
//consider your object class is Player
Player p1 = (Player) o1;
p1.getHeight();
p1.getWidth();
```

PS: if you need the Box2D world size, just scale it with your scaling factor.
Or better yet store it as scaled version in objectHeight,objectWidth while creating the shape